# update specific texture using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a human body shaped created in **MakeHuman** and exported the same as .obj files. Using three.js i am importing .mtl & .obj files, now i want to change the specific texture with the image. **I want to apply the image only to the specific texture**

```
var tex = new
    THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('b1.jpg') });
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load('sample.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload();

    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load('sample.obj', function (object) {
        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (child.material.map == "2_SkinTorso") // want to update only this material
                {
                    child.material = tex;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                }
            }
```

The above code is unable to modify the specific texture. Pls suggest

Thanks
shaik